# Static s3 site gives 403 error when on mobile or chrome incognito mode

Tags: amazon-web-services, web, amazon-s3

Whenever I access my site normally (not incognito) I am able to go to https://example.com and https://example.com/login

However, whenever I go into Chrome incognito mode or on my mobile chrome browser (not incognito), I get

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
```

and in console it shows

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
```

My s3 access policy is

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::example.com/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

and I have Block public access turned off. I use cloudfront to redirect http to https and that seems to be about it.

Comment: Can you provide more details on your cloudfront distro setup? Also if you access your bucket directly using s3 website endpoint, it all works?

Comment: I'm not sure which details would help so here are the general ones:

Security Policy TLSv1.2_2019
Supported HTTP Versions HTTP/2, HTTP/1.1, HTTP/1.0
IPv6 Enabled
Default Root Object index.html
Price Class Use All Edge Locations (Best Performance)
Delivery Method Web
Cookie Logging Off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I fixed it. My endpoint was example.com.s3.amazonaws.com but it should've been example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com. Changing this fixed it immediately.